# Can we create a new function into Redis?

Tags: redis

Is there a way to create a function and store it in redis, so that we get some values based on the function.

I'm trying to get values after some arithmetic operation has been done on the values returned, rather than looping it on my programming language (Which is time consuming as the values count is 10000+).

Can we create a function into redis and use it to call so that it performs all multiplication into redis and returns the simplified result?

Answer (score 1):

[redis eval](https://redis.io/commands/eval) is used to evaluate scripts using the Lua interpreter.

Here is a sample.

```
127.0.0.1:6379[2]> keys 'test*'

1) "test1"

2) "test2"

3) "test3"

127.0.0.1:6379[2]> get test1

"1"

127.0.0.1:6379[2]> get test2

"10"

127.0.0.1:6379[2]> get test3

"100"

127.0.0.1:6379[2]>

127.0.0.1:6379[2]> EVAL "local members = redis.call('keys',ARGV[1]) local total = 1 for index,key in ipairs(members) do total = total * redis.call('get',key) end return total" 0 'test*'

(integer) 1000
```

Comment: +1 for choosing Lua script as solution. However, DO NOT run slow command, e.g. `KEYS` or do complex operations in Lua script, otherwise, the script will block Redis for a long time, and decrease the performance.